# Selenium runs the wrong browser (default)

Tags: python, firefox, selenium

tl/dr: What am I doing wrong?

I'm trying to run selenium tests locally and be compatible with Browserstack platform. I use this code to connect locally:

```
wd = webdriver.Remote('http://xxxxxxxx@hub.browserstack.com:80/wd/hub', {'browser':'firefox'})
wd.get('http://google.com')
wd.get_screenshot_as_file('/tmp/googl.png')
wd.close()
```

I see a good screenshot in `/tmp/`.

Now I try to do the same with local Selenium:

```
$ java -jar /usr/share/java/selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar &
```

The server starts nominally. I try creating a session with Firefox (30.0), it works correctly. (Default browser is Opera.)

Then I try to run Python code:

```
wd = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', {'browser':'firefox'})
wd.get('http://google.com')
wd.get_screenshot_as_file('/tmp/googl2.png')
wd.close()
```

Selenium opens Opera instead of Firefox.
[image]

I see this in Python console:

```
Message: <html>
<head>
<title>Error 500 org/json/JSONObject</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 500</h2><pre>org/json/JSONObject</pre>
<p>RequestURI=/wd/hub/session</p>
<p><i><small><a href="http://jetty.mortbay.org">Powered by Jetty://</a></small></i></p>
```

Why does it open Opera instead of Firefox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
wd = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', {'browser':'firefox'})
```

Changing `browser`  to `browserName` will fix it.  Use

```
wd = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', {'browserName':'firefox'})
```

instead.

Comment: Same thing, it stars Opera that tries to work in debug mode. **edit** oops. Nevermind, it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (very close to the accepted answer) is to use predefined DesiredCapabilities [constants](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities.html):

```
from selenium import webdriver

capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX.copy()
wd = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', desired_capabilities=capabilities)
```

In this case `capabilities` is a dict already containing `browserName` property set to `firefox`.